# How to align list of item in a row in angular2 or may be with boostrap?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I looped a list of photos from photo array but they were diplayed one after another below each photo but i want them to displayed in a row, suppose 3 or 4 photos in a row. How do i do that?

```
<photo-item *ngFor="let photo of photos" [photo]="photo"></photo-item>
```

And photo array looks like below,

```
photos: Photo[] = [
new Photo('Dog1', '../img/dog1.jpg'),
new Photo('Dog1', '../img/kali.jpg'),
new Photo('Dog1', '../img/dog1.jpg'),
new Photo('Dog1', '../img/kali.jpg')
new Photo('Dog1', '../img/dog1.jpg'),
new Photo('Dog1', '../img/kali.jpg')
];
```

Comment: Try `img: {display: inline-block;}` That's not an Angular2 issue, that's just CSS.

Comment: i tried it before, but it didn't work.

Comment: What about a Plunker? Your question doesn't show what your HTML and CSS looks like which is the only thing relevant to your question.

Comment: i managed to do this with bootstrap class 'col-sm-3' anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely use **bootstrap** for this purpose . The process is simple

1. Use  `class="row"` for each row in bootsrap.
2. Give width to each element using `<photo-item class="col-sm-4" [photo]="photo"></photo-item>`
3. `col-sm-4` class divides each row in 12 units and assign width of four out of 12 units to your element.
4. For example you have 3 photos in each row you can use`col-sm-4`for each element which will sum up to col-sm-**12** .
5. One Last thing what you should do is , you should **formulate your loop** such that it should add only 3 elements **photo-item** in one `< div class="row"></div>`

**Note:** I tried to give you general steps . I can give you coded example if you need further explanation.

Edit 1 : **Example 1 (without ng-repeat)** :
In following example ng-repeat is not used , its just for explanation purpose. You can use ng-repeat for similar behaviour.

```
<div class="row"> 
<photo-item class="col-sm-4"  ....></photo-item>
<photo-item class="col-sm-4"  ....></photo-item>
<photo-item class="col-sm-4"  ....></photo-item>
</div>
```

This will add all photo-item in a row with equal width , according to available space. Important point is , any col-sm-x summing up to number greater than 12 for example if another photo item is added to above example with same class that will make sum of 16 .. only three will remain in one row , the rest of the items will be shifter to next row . You can only divide one row to 12 units. Explained better [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)